# Why am I getting this error when calling the method jasmine.Ajax.install()?

Tags: ajax, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-jasmine-ajax

Installed:

```
  npm install karma-jasmine-ajax --save-dev
```

Method call:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
      jasmine.Ajax.install();
  });
```

In package.json:

```
  Karma Version: "0.12.37"
  karma-jasmine-ajax Version: "0.1.13"
```

In karma.config.js:

```
  frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],
  plugins: [karma-jasmine-ajax]
```

Karma config file is configured properly, however, I'm getting this error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I got this error when the frameworks were like `frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-ajax']` changing to: `frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine']` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-ajax']`